# Best way to copy or move files with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, file-io

I was wondering, is there a best practice to write an OSX programm that copies or moves a file from one place to another?

- is there some NSSomething method I can call?
- Do I have to work with Input/Output streams?
- Or is the best way maybe to just rely on passing commands to the finder?

Bonus question: How do I get percentages a la "copy 12% complete" with one of these methods?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

NSFileManager and NSWorkspace both have methods to move, copy, and delete files. Usually you'd use NSFileManager since its easier to work with:

```
if ( [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isReadableFileAtPath:source] )
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:source toURL:destination error:nil];
```

However, NSWorkspace can easily move files to the Trash, which NSFileManager can't do.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] performFileOperation:NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation source:foldername destination:@"" files:filenamesArray tag:&tag];
```

Check the documentation for a more complete description of the two classes. ([NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: `performFileOperation` is deprecated in 10.11 :-(

Comment: To move files to the trash you can still use `recycleURLs`

Comment: @Klaas What replaces `performFileOperation`?

Comment: @matt See https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsworkspace/1530465-recycleurls?language=objc

Answer (score 15):

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error]`

Here's the link to the class reference:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:

Comment: Since the error parameter takes `(NSError **)` type, it may be better to suggest `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:dstPath error:&error]` with the & sign.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [FSCopyObjectAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) function. You can display file copy progress and you can also cancel file copy using FSCopyObjectAsync().
Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470360/944634).

**FSCopyObjectAsync is Deprecated in OS X v10.8**

[copyfile(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) is alternative for FSCopyObjectAsync. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470360/944634) is example of copyfile(3) with Progress Callback.

Comment: I love that you answered this question almost 3 years after I asked it. It's probably now more correct than the other answers as well.

Comment: its deprecated though in 10.8. Use the URL copyItemAtURL instead.

Comment: you can use copyfile(3)