# Recommended way to copy arbitrary files using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to copy file from one OS X volume to another OS X volume. While an *.app isn't strictly speaking a file but a folder, user expect them to be a unit. Thus, if user selects a file, the app should not show its folder's contents, but copy it as a unit.

**Therefore I ask, if there exists a recommended way to copy files using pure Cocoa code.**

**Optional:** Which **command line tool** provides help and could be utilized by a Cocoa application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use [FSCopyObjectAsync](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) function. You can display file copy progress and you can also cancel file copy using FSCopyObjectAsync().
Take a look at [FSFileOperation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FSFileOperation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003601) example code.

> This sample shows how to copy and move both files and folders. It
>   shows both the synchronous and asynchronous (using CFRunLoop) use of
>   the FSFileOperation APIs. In addition, it shows path and FSRef
>   variants of the API and how to get status out of the callbacks. The
>   API is conceptually similar to the FSVolumeOperation APIs introduced
>   in Mac OS X 10.2.

Example of FSCopyObjectAsync:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface AsyncCopyController : NSObject {

}
-(OSStatus)copySource : (NSString *)aSource ToDestination: (NSString *)aDestDir setDelegate : (id)object;
//delegate method
-(void)didReceiveCurrentPath : (NSString *)curremtItemPath bytesCompleted : (unsigned long long)floatBytesCompleted currentStageOfFileOperation : (unsigned long)stage;
-(void)didCopyOperationComplete : (BOOL)boolean;
-(void)didReceiveCopyError : (NSString *)Error;
-(void)cancelAllAsyncCopyOperation;
@end

 #import "AsyncCopyController.h"

static Boolean copying= YES;
@implementation AsyncCopyController


static void statusCallback (FSFileOperationRef fileOp,
                            const FSRef *currentItem,
                            FSFileOperationStage stage,
                            OSStatus error,
                            CFDictionaryRef statusDictionary,
                            void *info )
{

    NSLog(@"Callback got called. %ld", error);

    id delegate;
    if (info)
        delegate = (id)info;
    if (error!=0) {
        if (error==-48) {
            [delegate didReceiveCopyError:@"Duplicate filename and version or Destination file already exists or File found instead of folder"];
        }   



    }
    CFURLRef theURL = CFURLCreateFromFSRef( kCFAllocatorDefault, currentItem );

    NSString* currentPath = [(NSURL *)theURL path];
//  NSLog(@"currentPath %@", currentPath);
    // If the status dictionary is valid, we can grab the current values to 
    // display status changes, or in our case to update the progress indicator.

    if (statusDictionary)
    {

        CFNumberRef bytesCompleted;

        bytesCompleted = (CFNumberRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(statusDictionary,
                                                            kFSOperationBytesCompleteKey);

        CGFloat floatBytesCompleted;
        CFNumberGetValue (bytesCompleted, kCFNumberMaxType, 
                          &floatBytesCompleted);

//        NSLog(@"Copied %d bytes so far.", 
//            (unsigned long long)floatBytesCompleted);

        if (info)
            [delegate didReceiveCurrentPath :currentPath bytesCompleted :floatBytesCompleted currentStageOfFileOperation:stage];

    }
    NSLog(@"stage  %d", stage);
    if (stage == kFSOperationStageComplete) {

        NSLog(@"Finished copying the file");
        if (info)
        [delegate didCopyOperationComplete:YES];

        // Would like to call a Cocoa Method here...
    }
    if (!copying) {
        FSFileOperationCancel(fileOp);
    }

} 


-(void)cancelAllAsyncCopyOperation
{
    copying = NO;
}



-(OSStatus)copySource : (NSString *)aSource ToDestination: (NSString *)aDestDir setDelegate : (id)object
{

    NSLog(@"copySource");
    copying = YES;
    CFRunLoopRef runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"%@", runLoop);
    FSFileOperationRef fileOp = FSFileOperationCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    require(fileOp, FSFileOperationCreateFailed);
    OSStatus status = FSFileOperationScheduleWithRunLoop(fileOp, 
                                                         runLoop, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
    if (status) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to schedule operation with run loop: %@", status);
        return status;
    }
    require_noerr(status, FSFileOperationScheduleWithRunLoopFailed);

    if (status) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to schedule operation with run loop: %@", status);
        //return NO;
    }

    // Create a filesystem ref structure for the source and destination and 
    // populate them with their respective paths from our NSTextFields.

    FSRef source;
    FSRef destination;

    // Used FSPathMakeRefWithOptions instead of FSPathMakeRef
    // because I needed to use the kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions
    // to deal with file paths to remote folders via a /Volume reference

    status = FSPathMakeRefWithOptions((const UInt8 *)[aSource fileSystemRepresentation],
                             kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions, 
                             &source, 
                             NULL);

    require_noerr(status, FSPathMakeRefWithOptionsaSourceFailed);
    Boolean isDir = true;

    status = FSPathMakeRefWithOptions((const UInt8 *)[aDestDir fileSystemRepresentation],
                             kFSPathMakeRefDefaultOptions, 
                             &destination, 
                             &isDir);
    require_noerr(status, FSPathMakeRefWithOptionsaDestDirFailed);
    // Needed to change from the original to use CFStringRef so I could convert
    // from an NSString (aDestFile) to a CFStringRef (targetFilename)

    FSFileOperationClientContext    clientContext;


    // The FSFileOperation will copy the data from the passed in clientContext so using
    // a stack based record that goes out of scope during the operation is fine.
    if (object)
    {
        clientContext.version = 0;
        clientContext.info = (void *) object;
        clientContext.retain = CFRetain;
        clientContext.release = CFRelease;
        clientContext.copyDescription = CFCopyDescription;
    }


    // Start the async copy.

    status = FSCopyObjectAsync (fileOp,
                                &source,
                                &destination, // Full path to destination dir
                                NULL,// Use the same filename as source
                                kFSFileOperationDefaultOptions,
                                statusCallback,
                                1.0,
                                object != NULL ? &clientContext : NULL);

    //CFRelease(fileOp);
    NSLog(@"Failed to begin asynchronous object copy: %d", status);

    if (status) {

        NSString * errMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" - %@", status];

        NSLog(@"Failed to begin asynchronous object copy: %d", status);
    }
    if (object)
    {
        [object release];
    }
FSFileOperationScheduleWithRunLoopFailed:
    CFRelease(fileOp);
FSPathMakeRefWithOptionsaSourceFailed:
FSPathMakeRefWithOptionsaDestDirFailed:
FSFileOperationCreateFailed:
    return status;

}

@end
```

**FSCopyObjectAsync is Deprecated in OS X v10.8**

[copyfile(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) is alternative for FSCopyObjectAsync. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FSFileOperation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003601) is example of copyfile(3) with Progress Callback.

Comment: FSCopyObjectAsync is not deprecated.

Comment: No, definitely not. But haven't seen a reference with such an enormous amount of...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784230/displaying-file-copy-progress-using-fscopyobjectasync) for implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What do you do in the other methods declared in the header? Like didReceiveCurrentPath? Looking to implement this just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything. Thanks

Comment: If you want to display current item on progress indicatore, you can use didReceiveCurrentPath method.

Comment: Would you recommend handling this copy operation on the main thread? I am having difficulty copying multiple files one at a time as fast as Finder copies (to a remote Volume). If I opened up another SO question, would you be obliged to answer? :)

Comment: In 10.8, the `FS*` functions are now all deprecated. The alternative is to use `copyfile` if you want to implement a progress view or use NSFileManager if you don't care about progress.

Comment: Alternative for iOS? As far as I understand this is only for Mac OS...

Comment: @Fabiosoft maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414802/how-to-show-the-progress-of-copying-a-large-file-in-ios will help.

Answer (score 11):

[NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:@"path/to/source" toPath:@"path/to/destination" error:&error])
{
    // copy succeeded
}
else
{
    // copy failed, print error
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Except this fact: copyItemAtPath:toPath: error: aborts, if some target file exists. Should I delete identical target files first? Other method?

Comment: @SteAp it depends. You can delete, move, etc. with NSFileManager, so it's up to you if what would be appropriate action for that scenario would be.

Comment: OK, then I didn't overlook something. Another version of copyItemAtPath: with options doesn't exist. Thx again!